# How to enable eager singleton initialization for tests in Micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a case where I have a `@Factory` annotated class which creates a bean and invokes some code. I have enabled eager singleton initialization and the
bean factory method is invoked even though it is not used anywhere when the application is started. However for tests, the eager initialization does not work and the bean is not created :

Application :

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.build(args)
                .eagerInitSingletons(true)
                .mainClass(Application.class)
                .start();
    }
}
```

Config

```
@Factory
public class Config {

    @Singleton
    @Bean
    public Response response() {
        System.out.println("Invoked");
        //invoking some code
        return new Response("test");
    }
}
```

and the test :

```
@MicronautTest(application = Application.class)
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {

    @Inject
    EmbeddedApplication<?> application

    void 'test it works'() {
        expect:
        application.running
    }

}
```

so when the test is executed, the `response` method from `Config` class is not invoked even though `eagerInitSingletons` is enabled and it works when the application is started normally.

The question is : How to enable eager singleton initialization for micronaut tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using a custom context builder?

YourTest Class

```
@MicronautTest(contextBuilder = CustomContextBuilder.class)
```

Your CustomContextBuilder:

```
public class CustomContextBuilder extends DefaultApplicationContextBuilder {

    public CustomContextBuilder() {
        eagerInitSingletons(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have taken this approach earlier but it makes some of my tests fail because it overrides the `DefaultHttpClient` and the tests fail because of `uri` not specified issues. If there are no other anserwers, will probably accept this one.